# Output empty array - (asynchronous)

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I'm using 3 region and using a aws configuration for output Timestamp and Average.

But I don't understand why I have a empty array in my output.

I add the different configuration, share cw object and getMetricStatistics method details.

I don't understand the method for response asynchronous call

Thanks for you help

```
var arr = [
    { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
    { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
    { "region": "eu-west", "value": "http://****" },
    ] ;  

var GlobalTab = [];

var r=-1;
    while ( arr[++r] ) {
    var region= arr[r].region; //test
    var Value = arr[r].value ; //test
    cw.getMetricStatistics(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err){
            console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        }
        else {   
            var TabJSON = [];
            for(var i=0;i<5;i++) {
                TabJSON.push(data.Datapoints[i]);
            }
        GlobalTab.push(TabJSON);
        function foo(){
        return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => { 
        setTimeout ( function(){    
        resolve(GlobalTab)// 
        }, 1000 )
        })
        }
        }
    });
}
console.log(GlobalTab); //error empty array
let bar ; 
foo().then( res => {
bar = res;
console.log(bar) // 
});
```

Expected result:

```
[[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}],
[{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:32:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:26:00.000, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:29:00.000Z, Average: 200},
{Timestamp: 2019-01-15T08:35:00.000Z, Average: 200}]]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call

Comment: Yeah i see but i don't understand ...

Comment: Then read, there are well-explained answers in the post. The basics here is, that in your code, executing the `while` loop takes a few microseconds, then you're logging the value, and expect it to have been changed. Most likely the first AJAX wasn't even called at that time.

Comment: Ok, but i try to do someting with he function foo

Comment: What comes to `foo`, you can't access it from where you're trying it now. `foo` is a local function to the `cw.getMetricStatistics`'s argument, there's no way to get it out from there. Notice, that some browsers are blocking `foo` even inside the `if` block where it is declared.

Comment: So there is no way to display my GlobalTab outside the cw loop ?

Comment: Yep, you've to take the advantage of the different asynchronous technuques JS offers.

Comment: So it's possible ? Do you advise me to use which one?

Comment: "_Yep_" to "_there's no way_" ... you can ofcourse refer `GlobalTab` in a function outside the loop, but that has to be called from an async AJAX handler.

Comment: Ok I'm trying to find te good solution ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split your code into multiple functions to better see what is going on. The problem you are facing is that you want to access value, that has been returned from an asynchronous call in a main function (global scope) which is not possible due to how asynchronous calls work.

First, lets write a function that takes just one region as an input and returns a promise holding the statistics for that region returned from the underlying `cw.getMetricStatistics` call.

```
function getRegionMetrics(regionParams) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cw.getMetricStatistics(regionParams, function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
                reject(err);
            } else {
                var TabJSON = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    TabJSON.push(data.Datapoints[i]);
                }
                resolve(TabJSON);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Next, you need a function that will call the above function for each region that you want to process. Here, you can leverage `map` function to create an array of promises and `Promise.all` to resolve that array.

```
function getAllMetrics(regions) {
    return Promise.all(
        regions.map(regionParams => getRegionMetrics(regionParams))
    );
}
```

Your processing logic is done. Now, when you need to get statistics for an array of regions, simply call the `getAllMetrics` function and chain it with `then` method.

```
getAllMetrics(regions).then(res => {
    console.log(res); // here "res" is your "globalTab"
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Where `regions` is your `arr`.